# Ajax get request sending to incomplete url

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wordpress, jsonp

For i reason i dont yet understand, i can see in firebug console that my (first ever) ajax request is being sent to an incomplete url.
This would be in a wordpress site. Using ajax through a proxy.php on my domain to avoid Cross-Origin Request Blocked error.
The content of my proxy.php is:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$url=$_GET['url'];
$json=file_get_contents($url);
echo $json;
?>
```

On the page where the ajax function happens im testing with this:

```
<button id="srch">Search</button>

<script>
$("#srch").click(function(){
  var url= 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=6&gsrsearch=%22stones%22&gsrlimit=20&gsroffset=20&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json&callback=?';
url = '../proxy.php?url='+url;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success:  function () {
alert ("success");
    console.log(data);
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

if i use `dataType: jsonp`, i get this in the `GET` url :
http://www.mysitename.com/proxy.php?callback=jQuery1111036782271532490285_1408436867392&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcommons.wikimedia.org%2Fw%2Fapi.php%3Faction%3Dquery%26%23038%3Bgenerator%3Dsearch%26%23038%3Bgsrnamespace%3D6%26%23038%3Bgsrsearch%3D%2522stones%2522%26%23038%3Bgsrlimit%3D20%26%23038%3Bgsroffset%3D20%26%23038%3Bprop%3Dimageinfo%26%23038%3Biiprop%3Durl%26%23038%3Bformat%3Djson%26%23038%3Bcallback%3D%3F&_=1408436867393

if i use `dataType: json`, my console shows that the `GET` is sent to http://www.mysitename.com/proxy.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcommons.wikimedia.org%2Fw%2Fapi.php%3Faction%3Dquery%26%23038%3Bgenerator%3Dsearch%26%23038%3Bgsrnamespace%3D6%26%23038%3Bgsrsearch%3D%2522stones%2522%26%23038%3Bgsrlimit%3D20%26%23038%3Bgsroffset%3D20%26%23038%3Bprop%3Dimageinfo%26%23038%3Biiprop%3Durl%26%23038%3Bformat%3Djson%26%23038%3Bcallback%3D%3F

and doesnt contain the rest of the url im specifying.

could someone tell me why the url im specifying is changing/cutting off? what is this Jquery with long serial in the url address?

Comment: IMO you should urlencode the url param.

Comment: The jsonp call is appending the callback parameter necessary to pass back data to the "ajax" call. Refer to http://json-p.org/ for more explanation of that part.

Answer (score 1):

You're messing with the `url` parameter.
It should contain only the real `url` and not the variables you try to pass in                 `GET`.

Use the `data` variable to pass the `url` variable to your backend. Like:

```
$("#srch").click(function(){
  var url= 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allimages&ailimit=15&aifrom=stones&aiprop=url&format=json&callback=?';
  var urlbackend = '../proxy.php';
  $.ajax({
    url: urlbackend,
    data: { url: url },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success:  function () {
      alert ("success");
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

What you set in the `data` parameter will be urlencoded to the `url` variable in `GET` or `POST` and you should see it in your backend script.

Comment: if i slap my intended url http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allimages&ailimit=15&aifrom=stones&aiprop=url&format=json&callback=? i get the json string i want. when i implemented your suggestions i got the following url in the `get`: http://www.dreamteammovies.com/proxy.php?callback=jQuery1111025898469169217897_1408431968048&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fw%2Fapi.php%3Faction%3Dquery%26%23038%3Blist%3Dallimages%26%23038%3Bailimit%3D15%26%23038%3Baifrom%3Dstones%26%23038%3Baiprop%3Durl%26%23038%3Bformat%3Djson%26%23038%3Bcallback%3D%3F&_=1408431968049 leads to wrong html

Comment: @user3108832 But the `url` parameter is now correct. Have you considered a problem in your php script? What does the "wrong html" contain?

Comment: It contains a generic wikipedia message that you get when connecting to the api without passing the params (an error), what do you think might be wrong with the proxy.php code?

Comment: @user3108832 Try `echo`ing the `url` parameter in your php code to see what jquery is passing

Comment: afraid im lost here, i can add `echo $url` to proxy.php but i dont know how to check what it is it echos

Comment: @user3108832 you should see it in firebug response tab of the ajax call ;)

Comment: ok (had a mistake in my original url fixed now but problem persists). the correct url is: https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=6&gsrsearch=%22stones%22&gsrlimit=20&gsroffset=20&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json&callback=? what i see in the response after the closing </script> is https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&#038;generator=search&#038;gsrnamespace=6&#038;gsrsearch=%22stones%22&#038;gsrlimit=20&#038;gsroffset=20&#038;prop=imageinfo&#038;iiprop=url&#038;format=json&#038;callback=? it causes an error (click links 2 view)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59568/discussion-between-user3108832-and-paolo-casciello).